# Converting mpfr_t (or any other arbitrary precision library type) to __float128

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, arbitrary-precision, mpfr

I guess I have two questions really.

1) I was wondering if anyone knows a way to convert mpfr_t types into __float128 types in GCC. I've looked around and found a thread on the mpfr bugfixes site where someone discusses their attempt to write a converter from __float128 to mpfr_t, but it seems to have dropped off sometime last year.

2) If no one knows a way to convert mpfr_t's to __float128's, does anyone know of another arbitrary precision C/C++ library that *can*?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [gfortran's implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/gcc/fortran/trans-intrinsic.c?revision=166480&view=markup) for translating to intrinsics (the code is C).  It makes a couple steps through an intermediary tree structure but the end result is the same.

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer for now, but I *was* hoping to avoid having to roll my own. Looks like that's probably not possible. Either way, thanks for your help.